# SQL Server полнотекстовый поиск: with and all from

Tags: sql, sql-server, полнотекстовый-поиск

Запрос

```
DECLARE @SearchWord nvarchar(30)
SET @SearchWord = N'with'

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Sentences]
WHERE CONTAINS((Sentence), @SearchWord)
```

возвращает 0 результатов вместо N-тысяч.

Как задать на обработку в запросе зарезервированные слова?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чуть-чуть дополню ответ, который дал участник [Alex](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/204438/alex).

При создании полнотекстового индекса, как указано в [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms187317.aspx), можно задать список стоп-слов опцией

```
STOPLIST [ = ] { OFF | SYSTEM | stoplist_name }
```

там же указано, что

> Если список STOPLIST не указан, SQL Server связывает с индексом
>   **системный** полнотекстовый список стоп-слов.

Если `OFF` и `SYSTEM` по каким-либо причинам не устраивают, можно создать свой собственный список стоп-слов:

```
create fulltext stoplist SentencesStoplist;
```

Добавив в него необходимые слова:

```
alter fulltext stoplist SentencesStoplist add 'or' language 'English';
alter fulltext stoplist SentencesStoplist add 'and' language 'English';
```

Либо создать на основе существующего (в т.ч. системного):

```
create fulltext stoplist SentencesStoplist from system stoplist;
```

Выкинув/добавив определённые слова:

```
alter fulltext stoplist SentencesStoplist drop 'with' language 'English';
alter fulltext stoplist SentencesStoplist add 'stop' language 'English';
```

И далее назначить использование созданного списка стоп-слов полнотекстовому индексу:

```
alter fulltext index on dbo.Sentences set stoplist = SentencesStoplist;
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за развернутое дополнение. Отметил Ваш ответ правильным.

Answer (score 2):

Собрал ответ "по крошкам".
Кроме собственного списка стоп-слов (которого, возможно нет). Существует(!) список системных стоп-слов, даже для нейтрального языка в настройках каталога, как в моем случае.
Запрос к списку системных стоп-слов:

```
SELECT  stopword
FROM    sys.fulltext_system_stopwords ssw
WHERE   language_id = 1033;
```

Убрать его из каталога можно командой:

```
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[Таблица] SET STOPLIST = OFF
```

После чего, зарезервированные слова (and, or, not, any, from и т.д.) также будут возвращаться при запросе, включающем полнотекстовый поиск